# Data Type Mismatch and Policies must be valid JSON and the first byte must be '{'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-policies

I need to make a CORS Policy for my S3 Bucket.

In the console, it says the policy has to be valid JSON. I copy and paste their examples and immediately it errors stating they're formatted improperly. This is basically what I'm trying:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://localhost:3000",
            "https://mywebsite.com",
        ]
    }
]
```

Apparently something is wrong:

[image]

Comment: Where did you enter that policy?

Comment: @Paolo https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/bucket/<bucket-name>/property/policy/edit?region=us-east-1

Comment: Even weirder, I get the CORS issue, but then the upload is successful and file is in S3...

Comment: The setting should be under Permissions then -> origin resource sharing (CORS). Is that where you specified it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CORS policy is a standalone policy that needs to be specified in the origin resource sharing (CORS) for the bucket. You need to enter the policy that you have there.